# multi url allies for same node

Tags: 7, uri, .htaccess

I have set my auto URL allies to something like this "store/[node:nid]/[node:title]"

having node title in url will make it more human readable and better SEO.
the issue is I want to be able to access the node using this url "store/[node:nid]" only

here is the question again

my url is "www.site.com/store/1234/title"

I want this url to work as well "www.site.com/store/1234"

and even this "www.site.com/store/1234/new-title"

and even this "www.site.com/store/1234/wrong-title"

cheers
cheers

Comment: Try using www.site.com/node/1234 which is default working.

Comment: @VimalGoradiya if i set auto allies to nid only then this url wont work "www.site.com/store/1234/title"

Comment: "the issue is I want to be able to access the node using this url **store/[node:nid] only**" well so much for your SEO, if your page is indexed as `store/[node:nid]/[node:title]` people won't be able to access your page...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [symlink](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodesymlinks) for creating multiple urls you want. I try this and created multiple with pathauto too.

Comment: I don't think so this provides the solution as OP wants.